# SQL filter row / Get count of rows if data present in column between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL SERVER 2017

Let's say we have the following Two tables

PROVIDER

[image: table 1]

MASTER

[image: table 2]

I want to get count of all the ID from provider if column_b value of master is present in provider
Output should be like this

OUTPUT

[image: table 3]

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks like quite a simple `JOIN` and `COUNT`, if I am honest. Why didn't your attempt work? *Note: objects have rows and columns, which have a value, not "records".*

Comment: In addition, in the No. of Records Matched column, how are those values supposed to be achieved?  Nothing in the sample Provider and Master tables explains the values of 1, 0, and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery looks suitable.  Your description is a big vague (does the id also need to match?), but something like this:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*)
        from provider p
        where p.id = m.id and p.column_b = m.column_b
       )
from master m;
```

Comment: WE need to match two tables based on ID and if the column is present, then I want the count on how many matched

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` as follows:

```
Select m.id, count(p.id) as matched
  From master m left join provider p
    On p.id = m.id and p.column_b = m.column_b
 Group by m.id
```